# WPF's CollectionView Filter calls constructor of elements in list

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, collectionview

I have a CollectionView created from an ObservableCollection.  I attached a Filter to the CollectionView, and after the filter fires for each element, my Item's constructor is called once for every element in the ObservableCollection.  Why does filtering re-instantiate my entire collection of items?  Is this a feature that can be turned off?

Answer (score -2):

Whenever the CollectionView is re-created (such as by calling the filter function implicitly or explicitly), the datatemplates for the items are re-drawn (re-instantiated).  The CollectionView thus does not create once all gui items and then hide the ones not to be shown, but rather re-draws everything each time the filter is activated...

Comment: which means that if you have a collection that is to filter items that are expensive to draw, it may be better to avoid a CollectionView and simply attach the view to an ObservableCollection, and hide/show items as necessary avoiding re-instantiating them with each filter call...